# Updating selected item in JavaScript apps with immutable state

Tags: reactjs, immutability, conceptual, immutable.js, redux-framework

Let's say I have a JavaScript/HTML app that

- Manages items
- Has a concept of a selected item
- Gets realtime updates to items as the app runs.

If I want my app to use immutable state (immutable.js, redux, react, etc), conceptually, how would I keep updates to an item in the list in sync with the app's selected item, if they are the same?

If I am using plain JavaScript objects/arrays and mutation, then the selected item would be a reference to some object, and the list of items would be actually a list of references to item objects. If I change the property on the object in the list of items, then it will be in sync with the selected item because it's the same object.

How would I manage something similar if I am using immutable state?
If an update came through for an item that was selected, would I have to also remember to return a new state where the item in the list is different and the selected item has the same transformations applied?

One thought is to not have a selected item, but have a selected index, but when I reorder my list of items would I then have to remember to return a new state where the selected index is different?

Are there patterns for dealing with something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way I do that. You could change the reference to index to an item.id.

```js
class JDropSelectRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let items = this.props.options.map((option) => {
      if (option.type == 'seperator') {
        return (<div style={DropdownSeperatorSty} key={option.key}></div>)
      } else {
        let selected = Boolean(option.label == this.state.selected.label);
        let labelSpanSty = {cursor: 'pointer'};
        labelSpanSty.color = selected ? 'green' : 'black';
        return (
          <div
            id='DropdownOptionSty'
            key={option.value}
            style={DropdownOptionSty}
            onMouseDown={this.setValue.bind(this, option)}
            onClick={this.setValue.bind(this, option)}
          >
            <span style={labelSpanSty}>{option.label}</span>
          </div>
        )
      }
    });

    let value = (<div style={placeSty}>{this.state.selected.label}</div>);
    let menu = this.state.isOpen ? <div style={DropdownMenuSty}>{items}</div> : null;

    return (
      <div id='DropdownSty' style={DropdownSty}>
        <div
          id='DropdownControlSty'
          style={DropdownControlSty}
          onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
          onTouchEnd={this.handleMouseDown}
        >
          {value}
          <span id='DropdownArrowSty' style={DropdownArrowSty} />
        </div>
        {menu}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default class JDropSelect extends JDropSelectRender {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isOpen: false, selected: {} };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({selected: this.props.defaultSelected || { label: 'Select...', value: '' }})
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.defaultSelected && newProps.defaultSelected !== this.state.selected) {
      this.setState({selected: newProps.defaultSelected});
    }
  }
  handleMouseDown = (event) => {
    if (event.type == 'mousedown' && event.button !== 0) return;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen })
  }
  setValue = (option) => {
    if (option !== this.state.selected && this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(this.props.itemName, option);
    this.setState({ selected: option, isOpen: false });
  }
}
```